# Reliably running hundreds of scheduled functions every minute

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduler, scheduling, job-scheduling, distributed-system

I am building an application that will need to run hundreds of short running tasks every minute. These functions are not doing anything special other than making calls to an HTTP endpoint. I need a reliable mechanism for scheduling these invocations every minute indefinitely. Failures to run at the scheduled time cannot be tolerated. I have considered the following options for the scheduler:

- AWS Lambda
- Mesosphere Chronos
- Cron
- Python Celery

Obviously there is a trade off between cost, maintainability (I will need to update the logic of these functions every once in a while), and reliability.

My question is, which of these options would be the most appropriate if I am most concerned about consistency/reliability? Are there options I'm missing that I should consider?

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned, there are multiple technologies that could help you do this, I would say that the trick is more to find the logic flow/model to use.

For example, If the number of tasks are not fixed, a publish/subscribe pattern could apply, for this something like rabbitMQ or AWS SQS could be used.

There are multiple ways about how to submit a task to the queue and also how to de-queue, you could have multiple workers reading/waiting for events in where they could read one by one or by chunks (based on the num of cores per server) all this bound to the speed and precision you may want.

Scaling I would say is easier since if need more speed (precision to do all tasks every minute) just need to add more workers.

For more ideas check this article [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html) it covers a stream-based model / event-sourcing.